# Void pointers, memory assignment and valgrind

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory, void-pointers

I have this piece of code:

```
void *data = calloc(1, sizeof(char)+sizeof(float)+sizeof(char)); // line 56

*((char *) data) = 'a'; // line 58
*((float *) data + sizeof(char)) = 0.2f; // line 59
*((char *) data + sizeof(float) + sizeof(char)) = 'a'; // line 60

printf("%c ", *((char *) data)); // line 62
printf("%f ", *((float *) data + sizeof(char))); // line 63
printf("%c ", *((char *) data + sizeof(float) + sizeof(char))); // line 64
printf("\n");
```

And basicly what I am trying to do is save in the same memory region various types of variables and their values. To do that I am using void pointers and offsets of variables, and everything works fine, BUT, valgrind keeps telling me I have invalid reads and writes, and I don't understand why. Everything makes sense in my opinion, but valgrind disagrees.

Here is valgrind's output:

```
==5829== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5829== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5829== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5829== Command: ./a.out
==5829== 
==5829== Invalid write of size 4
==5829==    at 0x400909: main (Main.c:59)
==5829==  Address 0x51f6044 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 6 alloc'd
==5829==    at 0x4C2AA98: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
==5829==    by 0x4008ED: main (Main.c:56)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E83CEE: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E83ED6: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E7D9C0: __mpn_extract_double (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E843C9: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E83FFA: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E845E2: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E85504: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E7C2E8: __mpn_lshift (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E85508: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E7C2EB: __mpn_lshift (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E85508: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E85546: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E85568: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E856CC: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E85A54: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E7C904: __mpn_mul_1 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E85A6F: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E7C98F: __mpn_mul_1 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E85A6F: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E7CA02: __mpn_mul_1 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E85A6F: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E85A83: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E85A92: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E7C3F8: __mpn_rshift (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E85DF1: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E7C41D: __mpn_rshift (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E85DF1: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E849F1: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E7C904: __mpn_mul_1 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E849F8: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E7C928: __mpn_mul_1 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E849F8: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E84A40: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E836D9: hack_digit (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E84A58: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E7C904: __mpn_mul_1 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E836E0: hack_digit (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E84A58: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5829==    at 0x4E7C928: __mpn_mul_1 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E836E0: hack_digit (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E84A58: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E84A63: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E84A71: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E85093: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E85099: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E853BD: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E853E2: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E8541D: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E84BDF: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E84E36: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E84FF9: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E84FDB: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4EAFC4D: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E85C90: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4EAFC7A: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E85C90: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5829==    at 0x4E85C94: __printf_fp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E82D9D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4E88D28: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x400951: main (Main.c:63)
==5829== 
==5829== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==5829==    at 0x4F27C10: __write_nocancel (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4EAE14E: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4EAF8F8: _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4EAFD0A: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x4EA6A47: putchar (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.22.so)
==5829==    by 0x40097A: main (Main.c:65)
==5829==  Address 0x4022004 is in a rw- anonymous segment
==5829== 
a 0.199592 a 
==5829== 
==5829== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5829==     in use at exit: 6 bytes in 1 blocks
==5829==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 6 bytes allocated
==5829== 
==5829== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5829==    definitely lost: 6 bytes in 1 blocks
==5829==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5829==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5829==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5829==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5829== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==5829== 
==5829== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5829== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==5829== ERROR SUMMARY: 103 errors from 42 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

If someone could help me figure why is valgrind so angry it would be great.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you are trying to achieve data locality, you could simply create a struct. If you are trying to use a variable for multiple types, you should probably use a union. If you are just experimenting, cool, but this is a horrible idea for production code.

Comment: It has problems of alignment depending on the type of cpu. So it can not be used simply to directly dereference the data greater than char from the address of next character point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valgrind is angry because you're using the wrong addresses.

Your statements are all using **pointer arithmetics**, that's **not integer arithmetics**.

For example:

```
*((float *) data + sizeof(char))
```

Adds one `float` sized offset to data, not "1".

You need the correct pointer types for your arithmetic, and after you've calculated the correct offset, cast to the type you intend to use.

Comment: I am so dumb. Thanks alot bro!